# googleVis producing code instead of charts

Tags: r, googlevis

I am having difficulty getting googleVis to render plots. For example, when I run this code in RStudio

```
library(googleVis)
df=data.frame(country=c("US", "GB", "BR"), 
val1=c(10,13,14), 
val2=c(23,12,32))
Line <- gvisLineChart(df)
plot(Line)
```

I get this output

```
<!-- LineChart generated in R 3.1.3 by googleVis 0.5.8 package -->
<!-- Thu Mar 26 22:10:59 2015 -->


<!-- jsHeader -->
<script type="text/javascript">

// jsData 
function gvisDataLineChartID18a43b3b6397 () {
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
var datajson =
[
 [
 "US",
10,
23 
],
[
 "GB",
13,
12 
],
[
 "BR",
14,
32 
] 
];
data.addColumn('string','country');
data.addColumn('number','val1');
data.addColumn('number','val2');
data.addRows(datajson);
return(data);
}

// jsDrawChart
function drawChartLineChartID18a43b3b6397() {
var data = gvisDataLineChartID18a43b3b6397();
var options = {};
options["allowHtml"] = true;


    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(
    document.getElementById('LineChartID18a43b3b6397')
    );
    chart.draw(data,options);


}


// jsDisplayChart
(function() {
var pkgs = window.__gvisPackages = window.__gvisPackages || [];
var callbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks || [];
var chartid = "corechart";

// Manually see if chartid is in pkgs (not all browsers support Array.indexOf)
var i, newPackage = true;
for (i = 0; newPackage && i < pkgs.length; i++) {
if (pkgs[i] === chartid)
newPackage = false;
}
if (newPackage)
  pkgs.push(chartid);

// Add the drawChart function to the global list of callbacks
callbacks.push(drawChartLineChartID18a43b3b6397);
})();
function displayChartLineChartID18a43b3b6397() {
  var pkgs = window.__gvisPackages = window.__gvisPackages || [];
  var callbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks = window.__gvisCallbacks || [];
  window.clearTimeout(window.__gvisLoad);
  // The timeout is set to 100 because otherwise the container div we are
  // targeting might not be part of the document yet
  window.__gvisLoad = setTimeout(function() {
  var pkgCount = pkgs.length;
  google.load("visualization", "1", { packages:pkgs, callback: function() {
  if (pkgCount != pkgs.length) {
  // Race condition where another setTimeout call snuck in after us; if
  // that call added a package, we must not shift its callback
  return;
}
while (callbacks.length > 0)
callbacks.shift()();
} });
}, 100);
}

// jsFooter
</script>

<!-- jsChart -->  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=displayChartLineChartID18a43b3b6397"></script>

<!-- divChart -->

<div id="LineChartID18a43b3b6397" 
  style="width: 500; height: automatic;">
</div>
```

but nothing in the viewer.

Do you know why I am not getting the chart to display?

Here is my sessionInfo

```
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rCharts_0.4.5   googleVis_0.5.8 knitr_1.9       rmarkdown_0.5.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.6.8    evaluate_0.5.5  formatR_1.0     grid_3.1.3      htmltools_0.2.6
 [6] lattice_0.20-30 plyr_1.8.1      Rcpp_0.11.5     RJSONIO_1.3-0   stringr_0.6.2  
[11] tools_3.1.3     whisker_0.3-2   yaml_2.1.13
```

Comment: does browseURL work? e.g. browseURL("http://stackoverflow.com/")

Comment: @jebsel The particular statement that you provided (and varous variants such as:  browseURL("www.stackoverflow.com/"), browseURL("www.stackoverflow.com"), and rowseURL("www.cnn.com") had no impact but browseURL("http://www.r-project.org") did work.

Comment: should be "http://" included in the URL to work all the time I guess... anyway since browseURL is working this doesn't seem to be the issue. have you tried to put options("viewer"=NULL) before running the code? sure it isn't just showing it in the viewer pane of rstudio in stead of opening browser?

Comment: it seems like I am having some general issues with RStudio and HTML, see this post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329598/rmarkdown-and-rcharts

Comment: can you access:  tempdir()   in the R session that gives this problem with the plot() function ?

Comment: To explain: The plot command does not open a graphics device in the traditional way. Instead it creates HTML files in a temporary directory (viewable by tempdir() ) and uses the R HTTP server to display the output of a googleVis function locally. A browser with Flash and Internet connection is required. (also for rCharts which you uses in your other post with alike problem)  .

Comment: Thanks - I can access tempdir and this condition seems to have resolved with a re-install / retstart of RStudio. It is strange however the problem reverts when I run the same script in RMarkdown (and requires a restart). It is as if RMarkdown does something to my options that is only undone with a restart.