# RMarkdown and RCharts

Tags: r, r-markdown, rcharts

When I run this RMarkdown code:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r cache=FALSE}
library(rCharts)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, results = "asis", comment = NA, tidy = F)

hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
p2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', data = subset(hair_eye, Sex == "Female"), type = 'multiBarChart')
p2$chart(color = c('brown', 'blue', '#594c26', 'green'))
p2$show('inline', include_assets = TRUE, cdn = TRUE)
```
````

I get this: 
http://rpubs.com/rajesh06/test_Rmd

I also tried the "self-contined: no" option by changing to this:

```
output: 
  html_document:
    self-contained: no
```

but that did not seem to help.

Any ideas?

Comment: `rCharts` does not work with the new `rmarkdown`.  See https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/589.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my work I have a Mac and $show() works properly. 
I tried some of the code at my home's PC and for some reason $show() did not work.
However, there is an easy way around to solve this issue using the $save() function:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r cache=FALSE}
library(rCharts)
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, results = "asis", comment = NA, tidy = F)

hair_eye = as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
p2 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', data = subset(hair_eye, Sex == "Female"), type = 'multiBarChart')
p2$chart(color = c('brown', 'blue', '#594c26', 'green'))
p2$save("p2.html", standalone = TRUE)
```


<iframe src="p2.html" align="center" width="900" height="600" frameBorder="0"></iframe>
````

You can find the discussion I got this solution from here:
https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/373

I recommend you to use the $save() function as it actually allows adding controls to the rCharts in standalone html which $show() does not.

Comment: As a note - this corrects the sepcific issue I was having though I still can not publish to Rpubs. I will join the discussion on github to see if that can be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The more general solution (see [this](https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts/issues/373) thread) is to use:

```
p1$show('inline', include_assets = TRUE, cdn = TRUE)
```

e.g.

````
```{r results = 'asis', comment = NA, cache = F}
library(rCharts)
n1 <- nPlot(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars, type = 'scatterChart')
n1$show('inline', include_assets = TRUE, cdn = TRUE)
```
````