# Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection [Using R-Studio to plot interactive bar graphs using rCharts, knitr]

Tags: r, knitr, rcharts

I am getting an error when I am trying to run the code below in R-Studio 3.3.2 on a Mac (OS Sierra)

```
devtools::install_github('ramnathv/rCharts')
install.packages("knitr")
require(rCharts)
require(knitr)

haireye <- as.data.frame(HairEyeColor)
n1 <- nPlot(Freq ~ Hair, group = 'Eye', type = 'multiBarChart',
        data = subset(haireye, Sex == 'Male')
        )

n1$save('fig/n1.html', cdn = TRUE)
cat('<iframe src="fig/n1.html" width= 100%, height=600</iframe>')
```

Pls see output below:

> **Error in file(con, "w") : cannot open the connection**
>   *In addition: Warning message: In file(con, "w") :   cannot open file 'fig/n1.html': No such file or directory*

But I am able to generate the reqd bar graph in the viewer when I use:

```
n1$show(cdn = TRUE)
```

in lieu of `n1$save('fig/n1.html', cdn = TRUE)`

To take care of write permission issues (if any), I also tried including the line below, altering the WD path wherever necessary.

```
knitr::knit2html('Users/documents/n1.html')
```

But it did not help. I see the n1.html file created but it only opens an empty browser.

Any help to resolve this is appreciated.

**Best,
S**

Answer (score 5):

A lot of times we face this error due to caching in RStudio and in that case, actual code errors don't show up. Restart RStudio and this error will be gone and actual code errors would show.

Answer (score 2):

You have two separate problems.

The connection error appears because the fig/ folder does not exist. Create the folder and the save command will work.  `R` has functions to check the existance of directories and create new ones if you would like to do it in your code.

The second problem comes from the way you save, you should use `n1$save('fig/n1.html', standalone = TRUE)`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329598/rmarkdown-and-rcharts/29358467#29358467) you have a similar situation.

As a side-note, I would say `rCharts` is not currently developed or mantained at all, so I would recommend you to use another library for your charts. In my opinion [Plotly](https://plot.ly/) is quite nice. `rCharts` brought the `NVD3` project to `R` and the chart style is in my opinion really nice. However, as far as I know both projects are stopped so I would look for a library that is still alive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem was not the folder (i did have a folder by that name.) The code worked with `NVD3` library, and the `standalone = TRUE` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem with good old `rm(list=ls())` . I know I have
fallen into sequences where the error stops execution of my script.  I fix the error, and then it won't run. This is likely due to lazy evaluation but it is a near impossible problem to diagnose, so the solution at the top works almost all the time.